# Accessing props/state in React using this vs assigning to const

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Background: I (like many in programming) am coding a Reactjs application and have not got an educational background in Computer Science. In my case it was a scientific discipline. I'm coming up with a regular occurrence, which I would greatly appreciate clarified by someone who knows more about what's going on under the hood.

For each case of render() on a React.Component, to access the props/state I can obviously either;

```
// reference directly from this
render() {
    return <div>{this.props.text}</div>;
}

// reference from declared local variable
render() {
    const { props } = this;

    return <div>{props.text}</div>
}
```

Which way would be considered the 'optimized' way?

I may be wrong but I would assume that when props/state is accessed from 'this', there would be operations made on the component each time. Are these operations computationally more expensive than accessing a local variable?

I do, however, see it carried out from 'this' in many helpful articles/tutorials/stackoverflow, so my reasoning is could be flawed.

Comment: In general, if you have deeply nested object, say 5-6 level, creating an intermediate variable for a specific level is a good idea. It means less typing and less navigation. But for 1-2 level, it makes very impact and can be used as per preference. Also, don't try to over optimize. That is the main source of bugs

Comment: Ok. My terminology may not be great here, will edit. "Operations outside the closure/on the component"?

Comment: So no then? It's really just a good procedure where deeply nested structures can cause confusion in the code?

Comment: Retrieval of value from objects are done instantaneously. So there is a negligible difference in performance. But when dealing with deep structures, reading/typing becomes problem and hence, it is preferred to use an intermediate variable. As for performance, it will cause very less to even consider. Instead try for other forms of optimizations like using SFC. Less iterations for loops. These are more concrete optimizations

Comment: "Retrieval of value from objects are done instantaneously". That's what I needed here... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Performance shouldn't be a factor here whatsoever. Their only difference in terms of performance I'd say is that doing `const {props} = this;` is one extra variable assignment which almost certainly takes up a negligible amount of memory.

The use cases here are only for readability and which one "looks" better to the programmer.